# Issue with Upgrade to Hibernate 3.5 in JBoss 4.2.3

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, jboss, hibernate-search

We have been trying to implement a hibernate search with our project and in this case we had to implement Hibernate 3.5 previously we were using Hibernate Core 3.2. 
Initially we tried to upgrade our version directly to the latest hibernate search and hibernate core. But, in Hibernate 4 they have removed the TransactionManagerLookupClass.

So, now what we can do in order to upgrade our Hibernate to Hibernate 3.5. As we can't upgrade our Application Server because we have other applications running on the same server.

Currently we are using:

```
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-core-4.1.9.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-search-4.1.0.Final.jar
hibernate-search-analyzers-4.1.0.Final.jar
hibernate-search-engine-4.1.0.Final.jar
hibernate-search-orm-4.1.0.Final.jar
```

These are the files that we are using but, we know Hibernate 4 is not at all compatible with JBOSS 4.2.3. What we want to know that is there anyway to upgrade our hibernate core to a version where it's compatible with Hibernate search.

Secondly, the way be which we can keep the same application server.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a very old version of Hibernate Search which is compatible with such a very old version of Hibernate ORM.

A better alternative would be to download a more recent version of the application server like [WildFly 8](http://www.wildfly.org) and start using that for the new applications: you can use the old JBoss 4.2 for the old applications and use a new container in parallel.

Remember that you can run multiple different application servers on the same server, you only have to make sure they use different ports.